# CSS nav bar is unclickable

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress blog and the theme uses CSS to make the links work. On the homepage they work but on the other pages it doesnt work. I'm not a CSS guru so I wasn't able to figure out the cause. Can anyone take a look and see maybe what I'm missing?

Comment: Please provide more information. It is difficult to help unless we know (a) what you mean by "make the links work", and how they are currently not working; (b) what is the relevant CSS that controls the link behavior; (c) what is the HTML for which the links do work; and (d) what is the HTML for which the links do not work.

Answer (score 3):

Remove this css rule, because it will make your nav bar `#access` collapsed and so its height does not add up to its parent node `<header>`.

```
#access{float:left}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your div with the id of `main` is floating over the contents of your nav-bar.  Giving it a css style rule of `margin-top: 45px;` fixes the problem.